# Performance issue show/hide multiple divs

Tags: jquery, performance, animation

I have a rather extensive list of titles and definitions to which I have a show/hide effect applied to. Im assuming from the sheer amount of text and items, the speed at which this occurs is almost painful. I originally used code from another source, so it's not my work. I do know that the "read more" link that triggers the effect is set to come in after the page loads… this could be another reason for my issue. Im not entirely sure that it needs to be structured that way but I am a novice here and can only rely on logic for my current troubleshooting methods.

THE SCRIPT

```
$(function(){
    var slideHeight = 36; // px
     $('.jswrap').each(function(){
        var defHeight = $(this).height();
        if(defHeight >= slideHeight){
            $(this).css({'height':slideHeight,'max-height': defHeight});
            $(this).after($('<div class="jsreadmore"><a href="#">Read More</a></div>'));
        }

        $('.jsreadmore a').click(function(){
            var $targetSlide = $(this).parent().prev(),
                curHeight = $targetSlide.height(),
                defHeight = $targetSlide.css('max-height');
            if(curHeight == slideHeight){
                $targetSlide.animate({
                  height: defHeight
                }, "normal");
                $targetSlide.next().children('a').html('Close');
            }else{
                $targetSlide.animate({
                  height: slideHeight
                }, "normal");
                $targetSlide.next().children('a').html('Read More');
            }
            return false;
        });
    });
 });
```

THE HTML

```
 <div class="jscontainer">
    <h4>Other Procedures</h4>
        <div class="jswrap">
        <p>content</p>
            <p>more content</p>
            <p>more content</p>
    </div></div>
```

`

THE CSS

```
.content_sub1 .jscontainer {margin:0 auto;}
.content_sub1 .jscontainer h2 {font-size:20px;color:#0087f1;}
.content_sub1 .jswrap {position:relative; padding:10px; overflow:hidden;}
.content_sub1 .jsgradient {width:100%;height:35px; position:absolute; bottom:0; left:0;}
.content_sub1 .jsreadmore {padding:5px; color:#333; text-align:right;}
.content_sub1 .jsreadmore a {padding-right:22px; font-weight:bold; font-size:12px; text-transform: uppercase; color:#c44;  font-family:arial, sans-serif;}
.content_sub1 .jsreadmore a:hover {color:#000;}
```

LINK TO THE PAGE

http://www.doctorhtiller.com/procedures.html

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: Is there anything I can do to the script to make it more efficient or perform better? Or, is there another script perhaps that is better suited to my situation

Comment: Please add these sentences to your question. That's where they belong.

Answer (score 0):

Any browser will get overloaded when there are tons of items in the DOM.  The easiest way I know is to not load them all into the DOM at once and only load them as they are needed with ajax.  You can also do things like load them dynamically as you scroll down the page.  You can also remove items from the DOM once you are finished with them, but some browsers aren't so good at removing them from memory and can continue to bog down the browser.

Comment: This is obviously not the case as the amount of elements in the DOM are relatively small

Answer (score 0):

Bind the event handler outside of the jQuery each loop, otherwise you will bind the same event listener to all "read more" elements currently available in the DOM over and over again until the loop finishes.

Like this:

```
$(function(){
    var slideHeight = 36;

    $('.jswrap').each(function(){
        var defHeight = $(this).height();

        if(defHeight >= slideHeight){
            $(this).css({'height':slideHeight,'max-height': defHeight});
            $(this).after($('<div class="jsreadmore"><a href="#">Read More</a></div>'));
        }
    });

    $('.jsreadmore a').click(function(){
        var $targetSlide = $(this).parent().prev(),
            curHeight = $targetSlide.height(),
            defHeight = $targetSlide.css('max-height');

        if(curHeight == slideHeight){
            $targetSlide.animate({
                height: defHeight
            }, "normal");
            $targetSlide.next().children('a').html('Close');
        }else{
            $targetSlide.animate({
                height: slideHeight
            }, "normal");
            $targetSlide.next().children('a').html('Read More');
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Is that the "$(this.after($('div class="jsreadmore...." line? Im not sure what the event listner is. Sorry, maybe novice is a bit on the genreous side…

Comment: When you add an event listener you are binding a function to an event that gets executed when the event is triggered
Which in this case is "$('.jsreadmore a').click(function(){...});"

Comment: Damn. That made an immense difference. That is EXACTLY what I was after. I knew there was something wrong, just no idea how to figure it out… thank you. So the event listener is the top section? from "$('.jswrap… to …Read More</a></div>')) } });" ? Is that correct?

Comment: The the event handler is the function you are passing to the $().click(...)

Answer (score 0):

You could take this a step farther and turn it into a delegate as such:

```
$('.jsreadmore').delegate('a', 'click', function(){
    var $targetSlide = $(this).parent().prev(),
        curHeight = $targetSlide.height(),
        defHeight = $targetSlide.css('max-height');

    if(curHeight == slideHeight){
        $targetSlide.animate({
            height: defHeight
        }, "normal");
        $targetSlide.next().children('a').html('Close');
    }else{
        $targetSlide.animate({
            height: slideHeight
        }, "normal");
        $targetSlide.next().children('a').html('Read More');
    }
    return false;
});
```

What this buys you is that you literally have one event handler under the hood handling all a's and should you dynamically create more a's the delegate will already handle them unlike a click handler.